# Can't validate quantity after ajax load content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This is my example:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "some.php",
   data: "fname=John&lname=Due",
   success: function(result){
      $('#content').html('Label 1: <input name="quantity[]" class="quantity"> Label 2: <input name="quantity[]" class="quantity">');
   }
});
```

And js validate quantity

```
    $(".quantity").keydown(function (e) {
        // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, enter and .
        if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110]) !== -1 ||
            // Allow: Ctrl+A, Command+A
            (e.keyCode == 65 && ( e.ctrlKey === true || e.metaKey === true ) ) || 
            // Allow: home, end, left, right, down, up
            (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 40)) {
            // let it happen, don't do anything
            return;
        }
        // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
        if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Since your `.quantity` are dynamically loaded, you need to change `$(".quantity").keydown(function (e) {` to `$("#content").on(keydown, ".quantity", function (e) {`

Comment: as i have explained in my anwer, you have unbind the current events before bind the new events. https://jsfiddle.net/q52m0sks/

Comment: See the result if never do the unbind https://jsfiddle.net/q52m0sks/1/ (click on the dynamic items and see the alerts)

Answer (score 1):

[`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html) is a function where parameter that is to be set as new `html` is passed at invocation, unless [`.html(function(index, html){})`](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function) pattern is used, where new `html` is `return`ed at function callback; not set as a property value as `.innerHTML` is. Substitute

```
$('#content').html('Label 1: <input name="quantity[]" class="quantity"> Label 2: <input name="quantity[]" class="quantity">');
```

for

```
$('#content').html = 'Label 1: <input name="quantity[]" class="quantity"> Label 2: <input name="quantity[]" class="quantity">';
```

---

Use event delegation to attach `keydown` event to dynamically created `.quantity` elements; or attach event when element is created

```
function handleKeydown(e) {
        // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, enter and .
        if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110]) !== -1 ||
            // Allow: Ctrl+A, Command+A
            (e.keyCode == 65 && ( e.ctrlKey === true || e.metaKey === true ) ) || 
            // Allow: home, end, left, right, down, up
            (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 40)) {
            // let it happen, don't do anything
            return;
        }
        // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
        if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }

$('#content')
.html('Label 1: <input name="quantity[]" class="quantity"> Label 2: <input name="quantity[]" class="quantity">')
.find(".quantity")
.keydown(handleKeydown);
```

Answer (score 1):

As others has mentioned, you have to use the html() function properly.

By the way, if ever you create html content dynamically, you have to bind the events also.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "some.php",
    data: "fname=John&lname=Due",
    success: function(result){
        $('#content').html = 'Label 1: <input name="quantity[]" class="quantity"> Label 2: <input name="quantity[]" class="quantity">';

        $(".quantity").unbind("keydown").bind("keydown", function() {
            // your validation code should goes here
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

.html is a method u can not assign so follow like this for reference http://api.jquery.com/html/

```
$('#content').html('Label 1: <input name="quantity[]" class="quantity"> Label 2: <input name="quantity[]" class="quantity">');
```